# Silverlight throws exception when I try to write a string to file whose size is more than 8192 bytes

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to write a string(which is an xml) whose size is more than 8192 bytes to a file.

Exception :
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.dll

Additional information: The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 9322.

Have put the following entries for readerquotas in web.config, configuration.svcinfo, configuration91.svcinfo and servicerefernces.clientinfo :

```
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

Here the code which am hitting error :

```
    public void saveD2ConfigFile(string d2ConfigString, string generatedConfigFilePath)
    {

        TextWriter d2Writer = new StreamWriter(@generatedConfigFilePath);

        try
        {
            string[] tempArray = d2ConfigString.Split('\n');
            for (int iterator = 0; iterator < tempArray.Count(); iterator++)
            {
                d2Writer. WriteLine(tempArray[iterator]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        d2Writer.Flush();
        d2Writer.Close();
        d2Writer.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: (1) are you sure you're getting an error mentioning *reading* XML data when you say you are *writing* XML data?  (2) I can't reproduce an error writing 16K of made-up data to a file.  (3) Please don't catch `Exception` and do nothing with it, as this may be hiding an error.

Comment: Thanks Luke. (1) Am sure that the data is XML data. (3)Also, tried the same without catching the exception. Tried the same after changing the function as per this:                                                                public void saveD2ConfigFile(string d2ConfigString, string generatedConfigFilePath)
        {
            XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quota = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.LoadXml(d2ConfigString);
            xDoc.Save(@generatedConfigFilePath);
        }

Comment: Re (1), the point was not whether the data was XML or not.  You were getting an error mentioning *reading* when you say you are *writing*.  Besides, I don't see why you get an error mentioning XML when you're not even doing any XML processing in the code you've shown.